# What do the $placeholder$ tags in Package.appxmanifest represent?

Tags: maui, maui-blazor

I've attempted to refactor the starting example .NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid app into a Razor Class Library (the Data, Pages, wwwroot, and Shared folders) that the remainder of the .NET MAUI Blazor codebase references as a separate project. I've updated the MAUI usings in _Imports.Razor to reference the RCL. I'm getting compile errors however that the splash image for $placeholder$.png in Package.appxmanifest cannot be found.

I'm wondering what exactly this $placeholder$ in the appxmanifest is referring to? Is there any particular folder or location?

Comment: In no way am i an expert on Maui + Blazor but i am guessing its as the name suggests a "placeholder", you are supposed to give it a MauiImage from the Images folder...

Comment: hi @FreakyAli thanks. For some reason this placeholder works in the default project build without needing to change it (the solution compiles). But after refactoring some things into the RCL whatever it was referencing seems to be missing

Comment: Hi @user4779, how can we reproduce this problem? I couldn't find the `$placeholder$ ` tags in my app.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT hi this is in the default source code for the Package.appxmanifest under Platforms > Windows, for a new default .Net MAUI Blazor hybrid app in VS2022

Comment: Yes, I could find the `Package.appxmanifest` file under folder `Windows`. But I couldn't find the `$placeholder$`.

Comment: ```Find all "$placeholder$", Match case, Match whole word, Include external items, Include miscellaneous files, Entire solution, "!*\bin\*;!*\obj\*;!*\.*"
[redacted]\Platforms\Windows\Package.appxmanifest(14):<DisplayName>$placeholder$</DisplayName>
[redacted]\Platforms\Windows\Package.appxmanifest(16):<Logo>$placeholder$.png</Logo>
[redacted]\Platforms\Windows\Package.appxmanifest(31):DisplayName="$placeholder$"
[redacted]\Platforms\Windows\Package.appxmanifest(32):Description="$placeholder$"
...
```

Comment: Above is for new project created using the MAUI Blazor project template.